# SQL Server Agent jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent

Some related questions about SQL Server Agent jobs in Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

1. Is $(SQLLOGDIR) an appropriate place for job step output files
2. Is it valid to create stored procedures in the 'master' or 'msdb' database to call from a job step instead of having the SQL directly in the job step
3. What is the proper location for PowerShell scripts used in a job step? In c:\PF\...\MSSQL\JOBS, (sibling directory to DATA)? What is the best way to specify this directory, $(SQLLOGDIR)\..\JOBS

Thank you